# How to execute Redshift queries in parallel

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-redshift

I need to simulate some basic load testing against my Redshift cluster and I need to execute around 20 SELECT queries in parallel.

Since stored procedures are not supported by Redshift, I would love to get some ideas on how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Query Queue in work load management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initiate the selects in parallel, install this

https://github.com/gbb/par_psql

and then you can run parallel sql commands against redshift like this

```
export PGPASSWORD=your_pw; par_psql -h your_redshift -p 5439 -U your_username -d mydb —-file=myscript.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [WLM Query Slot Count](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-wlm-query-slot-count.html)

Check [Route Queries to Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-wlm-routing-queries-to-queues.html)